# How to render Markdown field in Vue3?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-nova

I followed the [Nova doc](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#markdown-field) and linked a `Markdown field` to a `TEXT database type`:

```
Markdown::make('Content', 'content_text')
```

I want to render it in the right format on my web app:

[image]

but it renders just the `string content` abolishing the format:

[image]

The `field data` is acquired like this:

```
const state = reactive({
    content: ""
})

axios.get('/donate')
    .then(res => {
        const data = res.data[0]
        state.content = data['content_text']
    })
```

and passed to the template like this:

```
<p>{{ state.content }}</p>
```

How do I make the Markdown work?

Im using `Vue3, Laravel8, Nova3`

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works. First install `marked` and `DOMPurify` libraries:

```
npm i marked dompurify
```

Then set them up in your `Vue3 component`:

```
<script setup>
import {reactive} from "vue";
import marked from 'marked';
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

const state = reactive({
    content: ""
})

state.content = DOMPurify.sanitize(marked(YOUR_MARKDOWN));

</script>
```

Then render it in your `template`:

```
  <div v-html="state.content"></div>
```

The `DOMPurify` library is supposed to `sanitize` the html and thus making the usage of `v-html` safe.

Oh, and if you experience the pesky `devtools warnings`:

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:3000/js/purify.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

that are caused by `DOMPurify`, I found it easiest to just block them by:

1. going into `devtools settings` (clicking on the gear symbol in Chrome Devtools) and
2. disable `Javascript source maps` and `CSS source maps`